# Neofetch custom config file - what is required config file format

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I have a question about using [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch). As per instructions [here](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/#using-the-config-file), `neofetch` can be used with a custom config file from the CLI in this way (as an example):

```
neofetch --config home/UserAbc/Downloads/file_config.txt
```

The installation is described [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/neofetch-terminal-system-info-app) but they dont mention how to custom config file.

Does the config file need to have a `*.sh` file format? eg. must the config file be saved as `file_config.sh` or can it be saved as `file_config.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On neofetch's first run the config file is created in `$HOME/.config/neofetch/config`. You can also copy the default config from `/usr/share/neofetch/config`. Finally you can also grab the config file from the github repo, here's the link to the config file for the latest release.

https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/e408e6f8d7c30c6fd649523522b51c3239b1364a/config/config

You shouldn't create the config file from scratch since you won't know what to fill it with. :)

I'll update the Readme to explain this better so that other users don't have this issue in the 
future.

I hope this helps.

- Dylan,

Author of neofetch

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking: in the way a `crontab` file can be created using `crontab home/UserAbc/Downloads/my_crons.txt`, would it be possible to do `neofetch --config home/UserAbc/Downloads/my_neofetch.txt`? This way the user can (a) use the provided file as the base, (b) modify as required, (c) save modified file as `my_neofetch` and then specify this modified `my_neofetch.txt` file as the config file to use when running `neofetch`. This was the reason for my question but I realize it might not be the most optimal workflow though. Thanks for your post and for the package!

Comment: No problem! Neofetch is just a bash script so the config file handling has to be as simple as possible. Something like `crontab file` probably isn't possible right now.

Comment: If you want to specify a custom location the easiest way would be to copy the default config file from `~/.config/neofetch/config` or `/usr/share/neofetch/config` to your custom location and then use `neofetch --config /path/to/custom_config`.

Comment: Yes, okay I think that is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Also, feel free to open any sort of issue on the github repo. I don't bite :)